# Crosswalk and push notifications

Tags: android, push-notification, crosswalk

I made a demo site for testing Service Workers and the Push Notifications, it creates logs in the console. [Demo site](https://lawliet616.github.io/)

It works fine with Chrome, but when I open the site with Crosswalk's XWalkView on Android and try to Enable the push notifications it gives me this error:

> DOMException: Registration failed - push service not available

How can I implement this service in my android app?